# How to populate a combox in datagrid with static items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm working on wpf application but not with MVVM architecture. I have a combobox in datagrid and i fill its itemssource statically. this works perfectly on my computer but when I installed the application on a new computer the combobox's itemssource is empty.

CommandeWindow.xaml

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridCommand" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProdCommande, ElementName=CommandeWindow,Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" ColumnWidth="*">            
     <DataGrid.Columns>                                  
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="prodReference" CanUserReorder="False" Binding="{Binding refProduit}" Width="150" Header="Référence Paulstra"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="prodCDP"  CanUserReorder="False" Binding="{Binding cdp}" Width="50" Header="CDP"/>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Statut du commande"  CanUserReorder="False" Width="160">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StatutCommande, ElementName=CommandeWindow}" SelectedItem="{Binding statut, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" >
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

this is my code behind

CommandeWindow.xaml.cs

```
public object StatutCommande
{
    get { return GetValue(StatutComProperty); }
    set { SetValue(StatutComProperty, value); }
}
// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ACCOU.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty StatutComProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("StatutCommande", typeof(object), typeof(Commande), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


public Commande()
{            
    context = new CRM_HUTCHINSONEntities();
    StatutCommande = new List<string> { "En cours", "Commandée", "Perdue" };
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to solve it. I just add RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window} to my itemssource in combobox

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridCommand" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProdCommande, ElementName=CommandeWindow,Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" ColumnWidth="*">            
     <DataGrid.Columns>                                  
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="prodReference" CanUserReorder="False" Binding="{Binding refProduit}" Width="150" Header="Référence Paulstra"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="prodCDP"  CanUserReorder="False" Binding="{Binding cdp}" Width="50" Header="CDP"/>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Statut du commande"  CanUserReorder="False" Width="160">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StatutCommande, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding statut, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" >
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```